# is it true if I change the order of parts in a sentence like this?

Tags: difference

is the sentence "교실에 컴퓨터가 있습니다" equal to "컴퓨터가 교실에 있습니다"? (I have swapped the position of "교실에" and "컴퓨터가")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have similar meanings. The first one has more emphasis on the object the latter is on location which is classroom.
교실에 컴퓨터가 있습니다 - There is a computer in a classroom.
컴퓨터가 교실에 있습니다 - The computer is in the classroom.

Answer (score 1):

Those have same meaning, but I think that

"교실에 컴퓨터가 있습니다" emphasizes the classroom a bit as usually a subject comes first.

It's like you're saying

"In a classroom there is a computer."